# Setting an Accounts Contact

Tags: apex, trigger, lead-conversion

So playing around just learning with APEX triggers, I am creating an Account and Contact when you create a Lead. So far everything works as I would like - however I wish to set the relationship between the Account and Contact(Contact links to Account and Account links to Contact). I was wondering how this was done I have looked at the API, and saw the 'IsPersonAccount' value, which just returns the following;-

> Invalid field IsPersonAccount for SObject Account

So my guess would be this feature either does not exist anymore or has had its name changed(obviously this is a beginners view) however this most likely is not the problem. What I want to do is set the contacts Account Name to the Account created, then set the Accounts Contact to the Contact created. I am doing this in an APEX trigger called 'leadContact' here is the code for said triggr:

```
trigger leadContact on Lead (before insert) {
List <Contact> conToInsert = new List <Contact>();
List <Account> accToInsert = new List <Account>();
for(Lead l : Trigger.new) {
    Account a = new Account();

    a.AnnualRevenue = l.AnnualRevenue;
    a.BillingCity = l.City;
    a.BillingCountry = l.Country;
    a.BillingState = l.State;
    a.BillingStreet = l.Street;
    a.NumberOfEmployees = l.NumberOfEmployees;

    a.ShippingCity = l.City;
    a.ShippingCountry = l.Country;
    a.ShippingStreet = l.Street;
    a.ShippingState = l.State;

    a.Name = l.FirstName + ' ' + l.LastName;
    a.Rating = l.Rating;
    a.Phone = l.Phone;
    a.Website = l.Website;

    a.Description = l.Description;
    accToInsert.add(a);

    Contact c = new Contact();
    c.MailingCountry = l.Country;
    c.MailingStreet = l.Street;
    c.MailingCity = l.City;
    c.MailingState = l.State;

    c.FirstName = l.FirstName;
    c.LastName = l.LastName;
    c.MobilePhone = l.MobilePhone;
    c.Phone = l.Phone;
    c.Email = l.Email;

    c.Description = l.Description;
    c.Title = l.Title;
    c.AccountId = a.Id;
    conToInsert.add(c);
}

  try {
    insert conToInsert;
    insert accToInsert;
  } catch(system.Dmlexception e) {
    system.debug(e);
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated thank you.

Comment: PersonAccounts is feature that needs to be activated, which it may not be in your org (I agree with Peter's answer below though). Link: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000171021&language=en_US

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are creating a Lead, you *shouldn't* create an Account and a Contact at the same time. Not if you intend to use the system in the way it was intended.

A lead is meant to be ephemeral and temporary. The minute you intend to establish a relationship to the person involved in the Lead, you convert the lead.

Lead conversion will automatically create an Account and a Contact from the Lead data, and optionally an Opportunity. It will also retire the lead.

There several reasons why you should use the system like this that I can think of:

1. This is how it was designed
2. The mapping of fields from Lead to Account and Contact can be done by a non-coder in the metadata for lead conversion mapping
3. Save yourself from mind-numbing boilerplate code like you show in your question

One final thing...if it is only a matter of ensuring the Contact is assigned to a specific Account, you do that when you set this value in your code in the question asked:

```
c.AccountId = a.Id;
```

Comment: "ephemeral" is a bit of an overstatement :-)  I'd say, Leads have their own lifecycle from inception to contacted to either qualified/bogus/dead/retouch later. Nevertheless, you are absolutely right - use LeadConversion to create accounts/contacts/oppos when Lead becomes qualified to develop into a business relationship.

Comment: Also, keep in mind, taking something that can be done with clicks and converting it to code means you will have to manage that code now with future changes on those objects, so you are not just creating more work now, but also more work for the future as well. No need to invoke job security, there is plenty of work to be done ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the [LeadConvert Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_convertLead.htm). This automatically creates a Account and Contact for you.

```
Lead myLead = new Lead(LastName = 'Fry', Company='Fry And Sons');
insert myLead;

Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
lc.setLeadId(myLead.id);

LeadStatus convertStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];
lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);

Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
System.assert(lcr.isSuccess());
```